# MySQL workarounds, which aren't working together - ROWNUM

Tags: mysql, sql

Goal is to iterate all rows in a table and update summary_total for each row, based on sum of ext_cost where ticket value equals ticket value for current row.  Could be a simple syntax issue or incompatibility with my version of MySQL - checking...  Any ideas?

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS TOTALCALC;  
DELIMITER $  
CREATE PROCEDURE TOTALCALC( IN _OFFSET INTEGER ) -- procedure with offset parameter to use like Oracle's rownum...  

BEGIN  
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;  -- declare total row count variable  
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;  -- set count up variable  
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table INTO n;  -- set total row count variable  
SET i=0; -- initial count up number, may be redundant  

WHILE i<n DO -- do while counting up to total row count:  
PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT TICKET:=@t FROM table LIMIT ?,1'; -- set ticket variable from current row using prepared statement to allow offset variable in place of rownum (workaround)  
SET i = i + 1; -- count up toward total row count  
SET @OFFSET = _OFFSET;  
EXECUTE STMT USING @OFFSET;  
SET @OFFSET = @OFFSET + 1; -- next row  
UPDATE table SET table.SUMMARY_TOTAL = (select * from (select sum(EXT_COST) from table where TICKET = @t) AS X) WHERE TICKET = @t; -- nested subquery workaround to update using/including data selected from same table  
DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT;  
END WHILE;  

END $  

DELIMITER ;  
CALL TOTALCALC(0); -- run starting at offset 0, which is row 1
```

Comment: Is the exact error message or unexpected behaviour classified?

Comment: I do not really understand what you are trying to achieve. Your code does not make sense at all.

Comment: Getting ticket sum(ext_cost) by ticket value for all tickets is easy: select ticket, sum(ext_cost) from table group by ticket. If you want to update summary_total field of the same table with this information, then just use this in a nested subquery within the update. I do not get the loop part either. You can use order by and limit if you do not want to apply the update to certain records within the table.

Comment: The goal is NEVER to iterate through records in a database

Comment: Unfortunately this elaborate and non-sensical method was the best I could come up after searching for a replacement for Oracle rownum.  Good example of what happens when you have too much caffeine and don't know what you're doing. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting aside a discussion about the table design, and why the `summary_cost` for a group of rows is being stored on each of the individual rows...

Processing RBAR (row by agonizing row) is a SQL anti-pattern.

We are usually much better off with SQL thinking in terms of "sets" of data. Rather than processing individual rows, we think in terms of processing a set of rows.

That whole rigmarole of a procedure just looks fundamentally wrong. Beyond issues like repeatedly using a `SELECT ... LIMIT n,1` without an `ORDER BY` clause, relying on MySQL to return the rows in the same order each time it is run, and relying on no rows being inserted or deleted while the procedure runs.

It's hard to figure out what that procedure is really supposed to be doing. It's difficult to decipher, and I pity the unfortunate soul that winds up having to maintain that.

---

If the goal of the procedure is to calculate a `summary_cost` for groups of rows in the table, and assign the calculated `summary_cost` to a column in each row in that group...

That could be accomplished much more clearly using a single SQL statement.

First, we write a `SELECT` statement, like this:

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.ticket 
     , t.summary_cost AS old_summary_cost
     , s.summary_cost AS new_summary_cost
  FROM table t   
  JOIN ( SELECT r.*
           FROM ( SELECT q.ticket 
                       , SUM(q.ext_cost) AS summary_total
                    FROM table q
                   GROUP BY q.ticket
                 ) r
       ) s
    ON s.ticket = t.ticket
```

The purpose of that is to return the rows we want to update, along with the new value we want to assign to the `summary_cost`.

If there are some rows that aren't supposed to be updated, or if we only want to update particular rows, we can add the appropriate predicates in a `WHERE` clause. We modify that query until it's returning the rows we want to update, and the new value that we want to assign.

Once we get the `SELECT` statement working, and we are satisfied with the results, only then do we convert that into an `UPDATE` statement.

(You are right to point out the restriction in MySQL about selecting from a table that is being updated in the same statement, and the workaround of using an additional inline view wrapper. We take that restriction into account when we write the `SELECT` statement.)

We just replace `SELECT ... FROM` with the `UPDATE` keyword, and add a `SET` clause (before the `WHERE` clause if there is one.)

And we end up with:

```
UPDATE table t   
  JOIN ( SELECT r.*
           FROM ( SELECT q.ticket 
                       , SUM(q.ext_cost) AS summary_total
                    FROM table q
                   GROUP BY q.ticket
                 ) r
       ) s
   SET t.summary_total = s.summary_total
    ON t.ticket = s.ticket
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this to me.  This helps a ton!  summary_total was the only column with data relating to multiple lines, so I didn't think to create another table for this.  Totals could be more easily determined from existing data when pulling, however there were other limitations on how we could process the data for flat files and pdf documents.

Comment: There are times there is a benefit to the "process rows in a loop" paradigm. But to do that in a MYSQL stored program, we would typcially use a  `DECLARE ... CURSOR FOR SELECT...`, an `OPEN CURSOR`,  and a fetch loop with an exit when no more rows (using an arcane `DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER` to set a flag and a conditional test at the top of the loop).

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you just use a `join`:

```
update t join
       (select ticket, sum(ext_cost) as sum_ext_cost
        from t
        group by ticket
       ) tt
       on t.ticket = tt.ticket
    set t.summary_total = tt.sum_ext_cost;
```

This actually seems awkward and like a bad idea.  Do you have a `tickets` table, with one row per ticket?  If so, the summary should go in that table and you can just fetch it using `join`.

Comment: Thanks so much - I still have much to learn about using joins, such as joining this way to the same table... but it makes sense with the subquery.  Worked like a charm!